# How to find all nonlinked subsites of a web page?

Tags: web

Is there any way, to find all subsites of a site? Even those, which are not referenced by this site.

For example: I have site *www.foofoo.de*, this site has 3 subsites - *www.foofoo.de/horse*, *www.foofoo.de/dog*, *www.foofoo.de/mouse*. Site *www.foofoo.de* has links to */horse* and */dog* but not to /mouse. However i can still visit site *www.foofoo.de/mouse* if I specifficaly write this adress to my web browser.

Is there any way, I can find this subsite if I dont know it's complete adress, just *www.foofoo.de*?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try to find out if it has a sitemap. Either it has it set to public and visible to users on www.foofoo.de/sitemap, or as a file on the webserver, reachable for bots like google on like www.foofoo.de/sitemap.xml

But the owner can decide, which sites they want to list on the sitemap.

Comment: It doesn't have a sitemap. Bots I've tried could find only linked subsites.